# Trying to understand the Swap Function in Python (get a Fail everytime I try to Broadcast a Transaction)

Tags: uniswap, pancakeswap

So Basically I m playing around on the BSC Testnet and trying to swap from One Token to Another. I tried to use all the Swap function(swapExactEthforTokens,swapTokensForToken,..supportingFee...) but I always get a failed Transaction or a Pancakeswap:'INVALID_PATH' error.
I looked on the other Transaction on the Router and saw that people often used the swapExactEthforTokens function when they swapped from WBNB to a Token: [example](https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x1d5976123975ba6a693988b70089ed19d77dc070ffda2bce28376d3fb5f2c858)

My Adress that Im using on Bsc : [Adress](https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x799Dc6750edc30d794C4249ECD83278a115791F6)

Code

```
pancAbi = {here is the ABI}
pancakeRouterContract = '0xD99D1c33F9fC3444f8101754aBC46c52416550D1'
tokenToBuy = '0xae13d989daC2f0dEbFf460aC112a837C89BAa7cd'       #WBNB
spend = '0xeD24FC36d5Ee211Ea25A80239Fb8C4Cfd80f12Ee'         #Binance Usd                               # web3.toChecksumAddress("0xed24fc36d5ee211ea25a80239fb8c4cfd80f12ee")  # wbnb contract
start=time.time()

# Setup the Uniswap contract
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=pancakeRouterContract, abi=pancakeRouterAbi)

nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(sender_address)


start = time.time()

pancakeswap2_txn = contract.functions.swapExactTokensForETH(
    14000000000,
    0,
    [spend,tokenToBuy],
    sender_address,
    (int(time.time()) + 100000)
).buildTransaction({
    'from': sender_address,
    'value': web3.toWei(0.001, 'ether'),  
    'gas': 200000,
    'gasPrice': web3.toWei('50', 'gwei'),
    'nonce': nonce,
})
signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(pancakeswap2_txn, private_key=privateKey)
tx_token = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
print(web3.toHex(tx_token))
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to approve transaction with contract.functions.approve() function before calling contract.functions.swapExactTokensForETH ().